# Firebase slow redirect after sign in?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I read here multiple posts about this, when user click *log in* , he will be redirected to `Google Auth` page, then back to the **original page** (log in page).

Problem : the function :

```
firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
```

Will be called only 3 seconds after user is redirected to the page, in the meantime he doesn't know what is going on.

Now - I don't care to show some progress bar - but how can I know that the page is being loaded **from a redirect and NOT just at the first time** ?
(I cant just show progress every page load)

> first time on page -> user login -> google auth -> redirect back/ show
>   progress bar

Answer (score 3):

The only way I found to solve this (not that elegant) was to save locally the fact that I am in the process of log in, then when redirected I know that I was redirected (and wasn't open for the first time) and show a loading window.

So something like :   `localStorage.setItem("onSignIn", "true");`

(if you hear that the delay is due to internet speed, its not true. we checked in multiple locations with high speed internet)